# Как получить список ссылок из списка ссылок?

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Парсинг сайта на Python. Есть задача, сайт-каталог компаний с такой структорой:

1. Список областей страны. На них список ссылок получить не проблема.
2. В каждой области есть список компаний, данные которых надо получить.
   Как пробежаться по всем ссылкам на области и получить ссылки на компании. У меня получается получить только по 1 первой ссылке из каждой ссылки на область.

---

Сорри, сейчас с телефона, нет возможности написать код. Но суть такова: отсюда https://krs-pobierz.pl/kategoria/wojewodztwo сохранил ссылки на области в спосок obl_links.txt. Далее, если зайти в каждую область, видим список компаний: [https://krs-pobierz.pl/wojewodztwo/dolnośląskie?q=](https://krs-pobierz.pl/wojewodztwo/dolno%C5%9Bl%C4%85skie?q=). И соответственно, нужно получить список линков этих компаний для того, чтоб в дальнейшем спарсить данные. Код прост как двери. With open obl_links.txt. Далее передаю в суп, find_all все блоки компаний (boxes) по тегу. В цикле for l in boxes:links_comp = find(тег). Get(“href”).    Собирает по 1 первой ссылке из каждой ссылки из файла. Каким образом пробежаться и собрать все ссылки. Bs библиотеку изучаю, но не могу ниодин вариант сюда прикрутить.

Спасибо.

Comment: Без кода непонятно в чём собственно вопрос.

Comment: Сорри, сейчас с телефона, нет возможности написать код. Но суть такова: